# PHP + LibPuzzle on Windows?

Tags: php, wamp

Hey all, I've been messing around with this awesome library on my *nix box, but would like to use this on my Windows test machine. Does anyone have any experience in getting this to work on a WAMP stack?

Can't seem to find any obvious answers on the source site:

http://libpuzzle.pureftpd.org/project/libpuzzle

I'm playing around with the idea of using this for symbol recognition in combination with some probability formulae to recognize patterns in image files. Would like to see if I can develop an automated, self-improving, image tagging engine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have searched, searched and searched, but there is no help on Libpuzzle for Windows...
I figured WAMP is a server like IIS, and somewhere on your drive is PHP's plugin-folder.
Oh, if just .so files could work on Windows... But no. We need a .DLL. Of course, I don't know how to compile Win DLL's from C source, nor do I know if it would work.

So; we need to figure out how to C Source -> Win DLL, then copy the DLL to PHP's plugin-folder, edit php.ini (Add one line, to enable the Libpuzzle), then just use it.

Tried something; didn't work.
Will update if I find out something.